# SQL IN Clause with string paramater list not listing all records

Tags: c#, sql-server, in-clause

I'm passing a string variable to an IN Clause in sql (Stored Procedure). When declaring and setting the variable in sql I get back all the data that is required. But when setting the variable from c# I'm only receiving data based on the first status within that paramater.

I've got a function to split the statuses in the paramater list to retrieve the records:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) 
    , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(10) = ';'
    ) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

    BEGIN
    DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
      BEGIN
        SELECT
           @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
           @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

       IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
          INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
       END

       IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
          INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList
          RETURN
       END
```

My stored procedure is built like this:

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[Get_RequestsAtEachStage]
    (@managerRef int,
    @status varchar(20))

    as

    BEGIN

WITH MaxStatusDate
as
(
    select rs.requestID,rs.status from (
    SELECT requestID,MAX([DateCreated]) AS MaxDate
    FROM [LoanRequest].[dbo].[requestStatus]
    GROUP BY RequestID) maxg
    inner join [LoanRequest].[dbo].[requestStatus] rs on maxg.requestid = rs.requestid and maxg.MaxDate = rs.DateCreated
  )
    SELECT lr.ID, lr.serialNo, lr.model, lr.clientName, lr.address, lr.telephone, lr.contactName,  
    lr.swop, lr.substitueOfGoods, lr.printFunction, lr.copyFunction, lr.scanFunction, 
    lr.faxFunction, lr.controller, lr.controllerEmailAddress, 
    ml.Name, wl.Location, rt.requestType AS RequestTypeName, rs.status 
    FROM [dbo].[loanRequest] lr 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[managersList] ml ON lr.managerRef = ml.ID 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[warehouseList] wl ON lr.warehouseID = wl.ID 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[requestType] rt ON lr.requestType = rt.ID 
    INNER JOIN MaxStatusDate rs ON lr.ID = rs.requestID 
    WHERE (@managerRef is null or lr.managerRef = @managerRef) AND rs.status IN (SELECT item FROM [dbo].[fnSplit](@status, ';'))

    END
```

Based on the page the user access it will send through the appropriate statusses and retrieve the necessary records.

Setting the paramaters in sql as follows works perfect, I retrieve all the records:

```
   DECLARE @managerRef INT
   DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(100)

   SET @managerRef = NULL
   SET @status = 'Allocated;Readings Updated'
```

But, when I send it through c# within a string, it only retrieves records with the status of Allocated.:

```
    string status = "Allocated;Readings Updated";
    DataTable dtDevices = d.PopulateDevicesApproval(managerRef, status);
```

My method to retrieve the data from sql:

```
     string filterstring = "";

            filterstring = "Get_RequestsAtEachStage ";

            cn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(filterstring, cn);
            myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cn.Open();

            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managerRef", managerRef);
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(myCmd.ExecuteReader());

            return dt;
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

--------- EDIT -----------

Running SELECT item FROM [dbo].fnSplit results from both c# and sql

Returning results from c#:

[image]

And returning results from sql:

[image]

Comment: Seems that the right way is `myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);` (note `@` sign to denote parameter). I think comma sign doesn't indicate separator on your query.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto, Thank you very much, I added the @ sign and changed the comma to a semi-colon, but that still isn't working...

Comment: What does `SELECT item FROM [dbo].[fnSplit](@status, ';')` do, if your run it from c# with the same @status parameter? Are you sure that it is splitting the values correctly?

Comment: @Lithium, Yes it splits them correctly, the results of both statuses does come through

Comment: @Kerieks - you might want to clarify your edit to state that running `SELECT item FROM [dbo].[fnSplit](@status, ';') ` from both C# and SQL Server returns the same results, otherwise the edit might mislead people into thinking the issue is fixed, or there's no problem.

Comment: You can get rid of all this code if you use a TVP instead

Comment: How about `@status varchar(20)` on SP part? I suspected some kind of string truncation happens when getting data from function due to `item` has containing correct data, then second status doesn't included. Use TVP if you not sure how the strings are processed.

Comment: @Kerieks - What is the value of `managerRef` in the C# code? Is it `null` or `DBNull.Value` ?

Comment: BTW neither `SELECT` nor `IN (SELECT` are broken. If you don't get the expected results, it's because the data doesn't match.  You don't need `IN (SELECT` anyway. The result is a table, so you could join with it directly `INNER JOIN fn_split ... as t on t.Item = rs.status`

Comment: VARCHAR means ASCII. If the parameter and column collations don't match, the strings won't be considered equal.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, could you please submit your solution? ...I somehow missed this critical mistake, it worked after changing the sp @ status to nvarchar(20)... Thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just clarifying: why passing `NVARCHAR` to a `VARCHAR` parameter resulting a table with `VARCHAR` element may differently treated when using `IN` clause? I think there was certain differences apply between ASCII and Unicode format.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto What is the codepage of that VARCHAR parameter? How are *Unicode* characters converted to that codepage? ADO.NET knows the server's and the database's collation and translates Unicode strings to that collation. If the *field's* collation is different from that, the generated VARCHAR won't match

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I bow down to your remote debugging skills! Now please post it as an answer so we can properly upvote it :-)